# Why is function.apply.length 2 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, apply

When I run this code on console:

```js
(function test(){
   console.log(function(){}.apply.length);
})();
```

The output is: `2`

I read about [Function length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length). I understand the function length section on MDN. But I don't understand this. There are no parameters in function. Why is the output 2?

Comment: thanks @jenny for editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're asking for the `.length` of `Function.prototype.apply`, which is `2` for its *thisArg* and its *argArray*.

[19.2.3.1Function.prototype.apply ( thisArg, argArray )](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.apply) `<-- two parameters`

Comment: Thanks @zack, now I understand

Answer (score 2):

Because of `apply` which accepts 2 parameters. Without apply it will show 0

```js
(function test() {
  console.log(function() {}.length)
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The length property indicates the number of arguments expected by the function.

For example:

```
function boy() {}
function girl(name, age) {}
```

If you check first Function length `boy.length` then the `expected output: 0`, Because the arguments received by the function is 0. Second function received 2 arguments, so `girl.length` output will be `2`.

A quick summary:

```
const fn1 = (a    , b    ) => { }
const fn2 = (a    , ...b ) => { }
const fn3 = (a    , b = 2) => { }
const fn4 = (a = 1, b    ) => { }
fn1.length // -> 2
fn2.length // -> 1
fn3.length // -> 1
fn4.length // -> 0
```

The last one, fn4, is the most interesting case.

Actually, I would say it is even more interesting. The interpret generally distinguishes between no default value and default value set to undefined; however, it has no effect on the function execution.

```
const fn1 = (a            , b            ) => { }
const fn5 = (a = undefined, b = undefined) => { }
fn5.length // -> 0
```

Surely, fn1 and fn5 behave exactly the same. The only observable difference is the function length.

As per the specs, internally, parameters without default that appear after one with default are ‘considered to be optional with undefined as their default value’.

```
(function test(){
   console.log(function(){}.apply.length);
})();
```

In this code `.apply()` accepts `2` parameter. So Its length is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the apply() method calls a function with a given **this** value as a parameter

Comment: Yes, but this does not answer the question.